# Why is this statement throwing OleDbException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am trying to create a paging system and came across a post in SO that included code for achieving this. However, when I run my query, it throws the quoted error. I have double checked code but cannot see error. I am using access 2010 as db. Can someone point out my mistake. Thanks

> The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that
>   is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

```
Dim Row_Per_Page As Integer = 4
Dim TotRows As Integer = 17
Dim Page_Number As Integer = 2

Dim oledbCmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Select TOP '" & Row_Per_Page & "' *, Count(*) As '" & TotRows & "' From [Select Top('" & TotRows & "' - (('" & Page_Number & "' - 1) * '" & Row_Per_Page & "'))From Postings Order By [Date] DESC] Order By [Date] ASC", oledbCnn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have a problem towards the end of your query, specifically this part.

*From Postings **Order By [Date] DESC] Order By [Date] ASC**"*

First you have two Order By's, and second I think you forgot a '**, [**' before the 'DESC]' at the '**[Date] DESC]**' of your first Order By.

---

**Edit:** That link was very helpful. It's hard to read such a long query like the one you posted on SO when it's just one line long.

Forget what I said before. I think the problem is in bold here.

"Select TOP '" & Row_Per_Page & "' ***, Count(***) As '" & TotRows & "' From [Select Top('" & TotRows & "' - (('" & Page_Number & "' - 1) * '" & Row_Per_Page & "'))From Postings Order By [Date] DESC] Order By [Date] ASC"

You're Naming your count field 17, and screwing up the code listed at that site. A select Count query should look like this.

```
SELECT Count(*) AS TOTAL FROM Table1
```

That would return a field called 'TOTAL' in Table1 that tells you how many records exist there.

Use the below for your query and it should work.

```
Select TOP Row_Per_Page *, Count(*) AS TOTAL From [Select TOP (TotRows - ((Page_Number - 1) * Row_Per_Page) From Postings Order By ColumnName DESC] Order By ColumnName ASC
```

Comment: I am a new user and following a tutorial for pagination. The square brackets confused me because I have never seen those in a query. This is the site that I am using: http://www.jertix.org/en/blog/programming/implementation-of-sql-pagination-with-ms-access.html How can I proceed with this. Thanks

Comment: Ahh, that was very helpful the link, thanks. I misread your query earlier, see the edits to my post above. You tried to add in a 'Count(*)' to get a count of how many records were found in the query, but did it incorrectly. The code above should fix your problem.

Comment: Your update code still produces an error of: The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.